# How to store product variant in mysql using codeigniter ?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to create a product table, which have various type product and variant for example: a t-shirt can have different size and color.
now,i want to store this type product variant in mysql using codeigniter..

Comment: You should search online for "Database normalization". It's going to be the key for you to learn how to create a database correctly. Doing so will allow you to create those product variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can product table with column as variable as boolean(0/1) if variable is 0 then product does not have any variant and in case of 1 you can have product_variants table which has product_id. Rough structure of product_variants can be like following:

```
Id  product_id  size    price   color
1      1         S       500    red
2      1         M       550    red
3      2         XL      900    Blue
4      3         XXL    1500    White
```